# Minor oil leak and very little white smoke

Tags: ford, oil-leak, taurus

I have a 2000 Ford Taurus (engine is a 24 overhead cam) and lately we've noticed a bit of oil on the engine and intake valve, along with the occasional, barely visible white smoke. It starts and runs just fine except for the oil leaking. I'll find a few drops on the ground but not much. Is there anything I should immediately check, like a seal or something that could've broken?

Comment: Can you post pictures, please?